# If field A or field B is equal to X

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I configure my report to pull in records where either Field A or Field B is equal to a given value X?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained it correctly. I just want to show records if field A or field B have X.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it didnt work for me

Comment: Why in your version do I not need to put {} around the field names?

Comment: I did type it in myself using the {}. I am new to Crystal Reports, hence why I created this post.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The Record Selection screen will configure your report to display any record where the given equation evaluates to `true`. So to check for two clauses, use the `OR` keyword.

The trick is that, in nearly every programming language, both the left and right side of an `or` to evaluate to true or false on their own. So rather than...

```
IF {yourTable.yourFieldA} OR {yourTable.yourFieldB} = X
```

...you instead need to phrase it like this:

```
({yourTable.yourFieldA} = X) OR ({yourTable.yourFieldB} = X)
```

(Parenthesis added for emphasis.)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. So I am using your phrase, but it still doesnt seem to be working.  
When I have it like: ({yourTable.yourFieldA} = X) OR ({yourTable.yourFieldB} = X)  
It only shows me records where X is the value for field A   
When I switched it to: ({yourTable.yourFieldB} = X) OR ({yourTable.yourFieldA} = X)  
It only shows me records where X is the value for field B  
It's not showing me records that have X in either Field A or B.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on my comment. I thought line break was two spaces at the end of the sentence but it's not working lol